# Converting Enum to String in Habarta

Tags: java, typescript, enums, pom.xml, habarta

consider I have an Enum in my Java/Kotlin code

```
Enum Animals {
  DOG, CAT, COW
}
```

With the Habarta.cz maven plugin, I can generate a typescript file definition for my client  application which will translate this into:

```
export type Animals = "DOG" | "CAT" | "COW";
```

My question is: **Can I change enums to string** so that the generated type would be

```
export type Animals = string;
```

The options in the config is `asUnion` (default), `asInlineUnion`, `asEnum`, and `asNumberBasedEnum`. Do you know of a plugin or some other mechanism I can use to do what I need to do?

docs for referance: https://www.habarta.cz/typescript-generator/maven/typescript-generator-maven-plugin/generate-mojo.html